# Hangman Game: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: arguments, println

I'm struggling with this very simple code: I'm trying to print off "_ " marks, with one _ mark for each letter in a word inputted by a user. Whenever I try to compile the code, however, I get "error: method makeLine in class game_3 cannot be applied to given types;  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length."

That seems like pretty clear feedback, but I don't think I really understand it - At first, I thought it was because I hadn't assigned a value to stringNumber, but assigning it a value didn't help. What's wrong?

```
/*Assignment: 
Write a reverse Hangman game in which the user thinks of a word and the computer tries 
to guess the letters in that word. Your program must output what the computer guessed 
on each turn, and show the partially completed word. It also must use pseudorandom
functions to make guesses. That is, it should not simply try all the letters in order, 
nor should it use the user’s input to its advantage. 
*/

import java.util.*;

    public class game_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            getIntroduction();
            playGame();

    }

    public static void getIntroduction(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*************************");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman");
        System.out.println("In this game, you'll provide a word for the computer to guess.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The computer will guess letters randomly, and assess whether");
        System.out.println("they can be used to complete your word.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Let's play!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*************************");
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void playGame(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
        String hangWord = input.next();
        int stringNum = hangWord.length();

        makeLine();
    }

    public static void makeLine(int stringNum){
    for (int i = 0; i < stringNum; i++){
        System.out.print("_ ");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method makeline expects an argument of int:

```
public static void makeLine(int stringNum){
```

You're calling it with no arguments:

```
makeLine();
```

What it looks like you want is:

```
makeLine(stringNum);
```

Edit: To be clear, that's what the error message is referring to by formal argument list(expected) and the actual argument list(what you gave it). The other common error message that happens when what you give a method doesn't match what it expects is "The method methodName(expected args) is not applicable for the arguments (given args). This occurs when the types don't match up: if you pass in a String when it expects an int, or if you pass in the right types, but out of order.